# SELECT * AS {table_name}.{field_name}

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to write the following query so that instead of just field names, the result "keys" include the name of the table the fields belong to.

```
SELECT * FROM books
```

The result should look like:

```
| books.id | books.name | etc.
| 1        | She        |
| 2        | Lolita     |
```

Comment: Why would you need the tablenames? You do the query right?

Comment: I need a way to select all data from multiple joined tables. Some of these tables have field names that other tables have. I need to be able to distinguish them.

Comment: That's what `as` is for. You create an alias for a fieldname.

Comment: I need a more automatic approach than using `AS` for each field.

Comment: If you don't want to write the query yourself and use an automatic means to do so.. Could you tell us what you've tried so far? What are the restrictions for the approach you need? Are you using a scripting/programming language that you integrate this with? Optional parameters? Limited to stored procedures (meaning mysql level only)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan query mysql via a programming language, all the mysql drivers I've come across have access to the table name(s) when retrieving result sets. So, you don't need to change your query to rename columns to include the table name...you can just do it with code.

In your programming language of choice, look for a function that has a name similar to "meta data". That's likely one of the functions you'll need.

Comment: For example, with PHP: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php and with C: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-fetch-fields.html

Answer (score 4):

You have to alias them individually..

```
SELECT id as 'books.id', name as 'books.name' FROM books
```

Comment: This should also work... 

SELECT id as [books.id], name as [books.name] FROM books

Comment: what db do you use? if you have time, can you please check if enclosing it in `'` works on your database, because in oracle it doesn't work, I just want to know if this is db dependent, and I don't have mysql or other db avail., thank you

Comment: I've tested this on MySQL 5.1.54

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id as "books.id", name as "books.name" FROM books
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work.. the `books.id` name must be enclosed in quotes, since the `.` has special meaning..

Comment: yes, I just checked it on oracle, and it works with " but not with ', thank you

Comment: I need a more automatic approach than using AS for each field.